# Side Menu stopped working after new update

Tags: codenameone

I have an app that has a nice side menu that comes from the left, after today's update it is completely empty when it slides out and I have no idea why.

here is how I show it,

```
  SideMenuBar smb = (SideMenuBar) Display.getInstance().getCurrent().getMenuBar();        
    smb.openMenu(null);
```

Here is how it is created (remember this worked perfectly until today when I updated libs):

```
 private void addSideMenuToLeft(Form f)
    {
        _("addSideMenuToLeft");       

        //make a toolbarForLeftMenu so we can use its sidemenu (we can only have one on the left!)
        if (toolbarForLeftMenu==null)
        {
            toolbarForLeftMenu = new Toolbar();
        }            
        toolbarForLeftMenu.setHidden(true);
        f.setToolbar(toolbarForLeftMenu);

        if (SideMenuLEFT==null) //otherwise it keeps adding each time
        {
            SideMenuLEFT = (Container)this.createContainer(resources, "SideMenuLEFT");
            SideMenuLEFT.setWidth(Display.getInstance().getDisplayWidth()/2);
            SideMenuLEFT.setHeight((Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight()));

            SideMenuLEFT.setUIID("SideNavigationPanel");//so we get the nice background.
            toolbarForLeftMenu.setUIID("Container");
            toolbarForLeftMenu.addComponentToSideMenu(SideMenuLEFT);

            //make each button live, there are 2 buttons the icon and the words, for each one        
            Button btCategory = (Button) Tools.findByNameX("btCategory", SideMenuLEFT,sm );
            btCategory.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                    
                }
            });

            _("made left menu");
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We deprecated the `SideMenuBar` and replaced it with the new on-top side menu. It was announced multiple times and [discussed quite a bit](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/pixel-perfect-on-top-menu.html).

To disable this and use the "old" functionality you can use:

```
Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(false);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks Shai! Hard to know how to deal with things like that because you cant expect people to know the contents of your blog etc, but at the same time you should be able to depreciate things.

Comment: Generally we try to be compatible when moving to the new on-top mode but it seems your code relied on internal nuanced behavior that we couldn't support moving forward.